# configurable product with extra preview

Tags: configurable-product

I have a situation that suits best a configurable product. The best approach to what I need is this http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-configurable-product.

What I need more is the system to show another piece of information when a user selects an option like this:

[image: Configurable option text]

Is there  any possiblity I can do this from the Magento admin or would this require extra development?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you looking for an individual description for each option? ie. colour (blue|red), size (small|medium)? Or just one overall description after the user selects all options?

Comment: Each option should have its own description. For example if i choose one option I should be able to see a generous description of that option.

Comment: Got you. Not sure of anything on the market to accommodate this, but this is probably a good place to start - http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10214/looking-for-a-way-to-extend-attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question:

> Is there any possiblity I can do this from the Magento admin or would this require extra development?

No, there is no possibility to do this in the backend. There is no possibility to add or change these strings and no JS is implemented to show these texts.

So yes, this requires extra development

## How to do it

### Without administration and translation

If the list for the options is not too long and you don't want to administrate it easily or user should do this, you can just add a few lines JS.

1. Register onchange-Handler on the `<select>`
2. Add JS-File with the texts

The problem here is, that you can't translate in JS files.

### With translation

The alternative is to add a template, then you can use magentos translation: `$helper->__('english string')`

### With translation and administration

If you want to have it easily translated in the backend you have to invest a lot of work and write a whole module, extend the attributes and add texts in the backend to be changed